# writing a for loop in js for specific situation

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to write a for loop condition where:

1. The count of `"*"` is always ascending and shouldn't skip a number and `"*"` can be of `n` count.
2. `"*"` count can repeat like `"*","**","**","***"` as long as they are in ascending.
3. `"*"` count can be in descending too and shouldn't skip a number like `"*","**","**","***","****","**","*","**"`

I am not able to write the 3rd statement could anyone help me with this problem statement.

Check the following code:

```
let tocStars = ['*', '**', '***', '*****']; 
let valid = true; 
let count = 1; 
for (let i = 0; i < tocStars.length; i++) {
 if (tocStars[i].length >= count) {
 if (tocStars[i].length !== count) {
 valid = false; break; } count++; } }
 if (valid) { console.log("Valid pattern"); } else { console.log("Invalid pattern"); }
```

Comment: Please give us a proper explanation of what actually needs to be achieved here first of all, before you focus on any "conditions."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you're trying to achieve ?

```js
function isValid(array) {
  let valid = true;
  let counter = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    
    // Remove the line below if not relevant to your case
    // I assumed that when there is no character, the pattern is invalid?
    if (counter === 0) {
      valid = false;
      break;
    };

    if (array[i].length === counter) {
      continue;
    }

    if (array[i].length === counter + 1) {
      counter++;
      continue;
    }

    if (array[i].length === counter - 1) {
      counter--;
      continue;
    }

    valid = false;
    break;
  }

  if (valid) {
    console.log(array + " is a valid pattern");
  } else {
    console.log(array + " is NOT a valid pattern");
  }
}

isValid(["*", "**", "***", "*****"]); // is NOT a valid pattern (skips one ascending)
isValid(["*", "**", "**", "***", "****", "**", "*", "**"]); // is NOT a valid pattern (skips one descending)
isValid(["*", "", "*"]); // is NOT a valid pattern (blank character)
isValid(["*", "**", "***", "****"]); // is a valid pattern
isValid(["*", "**", "**", "***", "****", "***", "**", "*", "**", "***"]); // is a valid pattern
```